# Why does the Lagarith Lossless Video Codec (LAGS) not work on Python?

Tags: python, video-processing, codec, opencv, fourcc

I am trying to save 2 videos from my laptop camera with the same size and pixel values of the frames, using **OpenCV** with Python.
I'm changing the RGB values of some pixels in frames in the second video.
I want to save the videos **without** any difference between them, except the pixels that i change, but when i use **cv2.VideoWriter** there is a fourcc codec that compresses the videos and i am failing my project, because i want to 
retrieve the changed information in the pixels later. The videos go different size and different pixels values.
For example with the following code i recorded a one second video and save it twice (the second video is with changed pixels).

```
import cv2
from numpy import *
# Create a VideoCapture object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Check if camera opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened() == False): 
  print("Unable to read camera feed")

# Get the default resolution.
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

out = cv2.VideoWriter('outpy.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID"), 25, (frame_width,frame_height))
out2 = cv2.VideoWriter('outpy2.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID"), 25, (frame_width,frame_height))
while(True):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True: 

    # changing the BGR values 
    out.write(frame)
    frame[1,1,0] = 255
    frame[1,1,1] = 255
    frame[1,1,2] = 255
    out2.write(frame)

    # Display the resulting frame    
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

  # Break the loop
  else:
    break 

# When everything done, release the video capture and video write objects
cap.release()
out.release()
out2.release()
# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The size of the first video is *314 120 bytes* and the second one is *314 452 bytes*, also the values of the frame pixels in the videos are different.
So i tried to use " Lagarith Lossless Video Codec " to avoid the compression like: `out=cv2.VideoWriter('outpy.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"LAGS"), 25, (frame_width,frame_height))`, but i receive an error: **Could not find encoder for codec id 146: Encoder not found.**
After this I tried to download the LAGS codec from : https://lags.leetcode.net/codec.html with the first link, i installed the codec and i got the same error. I dont know where the problem is.
If i'm not wrong, my problem is because of the compression with the fourcc codec. Is the LAGS codec a solution and if it's not, please suggest a method to solve it.

Comment: Could you write the frames as uncompressed images (like a tiff) then use ffmpeg to make a raw video file from those frames? eg is writing the video with opencv a requirement?

Comment: That's probably a good idea. If i save the frame as .bmp picture the data will be kept, right ? Using opencv it's not a requirement, I just haven't worked with FFMPEG. I am still new to Python and I am currently working on a video-proccessing project. I just found a lot of information about opencv and spent a lot of time searching for this library and when I did almost everything that I want, I found this problem with saving the video.  If you have any other alternatives for the code or something that can help me, I will be thankful !

Comment: How did you install Python OpenCV module? It's probably compiled without LAGS support.

Comment: E.g. check out `print cv2.getBuildInformation()` output.

Comment: I installed OpenCV 4.0.0 via pip "pip install opencv-python".

Comment: Actually,  NateTheGrate helped me a lot to solve my problem! I saved the frames as .bmp images and then i used FFMPEG to make a raw video ! From the changed frames i made a second video and the size is exactly the same as the first video.  NateTheGrate, please write it like an answer so i can rate it  !
And one last question: why does VLC player produce black screen from these videos but they work on Winamp ?